# Antipode action on quantum minors

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, determinants

Let ${\cal O}(SU_q(n))$ be the standard $q$-deformed coordinate algebra of $SU(n)$, with the canonical generators $x_{i,j}$. For $I = \{i_1,\ldots, i_r\}, J=\{j_1,\ldots,j_r\}\subseteq \{1, \ldots,n\}$, we define the **quantum minor** associated to $I,J$ to be the element
$$
[I;J] = \sum_{\pi \in S_r} (-q)^{\ell(\pi)}x_{j_{\pi(1)},i_1} x_{j_{\pi(2)},i_2} \cdots x_{j_{\pi(r)},i_r}
$$
with summation taken over permutation in $r$ elements.

**Is there a formula for how the antipode $S$ of ${\cal O}(SU_q(n))$ acts on $[I]$?** My guess would be that 
$$
S([I;J] = [J^c:I^c],
$$
where superscript $c$ means complement in the set $\{1,\ldots, n\}$.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to $\mathcal{O}(SU_q(n))$?